# How to remove records from a vector by checking for equivalence?

Tags: clojure

In java I can do something like this:

```
myList.add(myObj);
```

then remove it like this

```
myList.remove(myObj);
```

This works by using the `equals` method and checking each element in `myList` for equivalence.

In clojure I can do this:

```
(def myvec [myrecord])
```

but I can't remove `myrecord` from `myvec` using `remove` like this:

```
(remove myrecord myvec)
```

because I get an error:

```
ClassCastException myproj.Task cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn  clojure.core/complement/fn--4611 (core.clj:1392)
```

How can I remove records from vectors in a way similar to the java method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove expects a function that runs over every item in your collection, and it keeps only the items that the function returned a falsey value on. In your case the error message is correct by telling you that your object is not a function.

You could either explicitly write a function that uses `equals` on your object, or you could add the object you want to remove to a set. A set acts as a function that returns a truthy value when its input is a member of that set.

```
(remove #{myrecord} myvec)
```

A concrete example

```
(remove #{4 3} [1 2 3 4]) 
;=> (1 2)
```

Comment: "A set acts as a function that returns a truthy value when its input is a member of that set." Incorrect. For instance, `#{nil false}`.

Comment: well, for all sets other than the "false sets" :) nice one Sam

Comment: Right, so in this case, since assumedly `myrecord` is not falsey, a set should work fine.